# SQL Agent File could not be found

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, sql-agent

This SQL job has been working for years on SQL Server 2000. I decided to move this SQL job to SQL server 2012.

I ran the job as normal, but keep getting the following error:

> Error Code: 0  Error Source= Microsoft Word  Error Description: This
>   file could not be found.    Error on Line 21.  The step failed. It
>   cannot locate the .dot file which is on a separate server.

**Am I missing something now that it's on an update server?**

```
oA2.Open "SELECT ID, Field1, Field2, Field2 FROM tblAppMapping WHERE Field2 is NOT NULL ORDER BY ID"

Set oW = CreateObject("Word.Application")

If oA("FileID") = "2" Then
   oW.Documents.Add "\\fileserver\WordTemplates\Template App V1.dot"
Else
   oW.Documents.Add "\\fileserver\WordTemplates\Template App V2.dot"
End If
```

Comment: eeeeeeeeekkkk!! Your DBA allows you to COM create Word on SQL server? Bad DBA, Bad!

Comment: It locates the template .dot file and fills in the form according to the bookmark on the .dot file from a sql table.

Comment: I can see that. Your point is?

Comment: The error message I get now is "This file could not be found". Is my format correct now that it's on a newer server or should it be written differently.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the SQL Agent and/or SQL Server service account has no access to `\\fileserver\WordTemplates`, although the best solution would be to move your logic into an external application or service that queries SQL Server for the data and creates the documents. Then you have much more flexibility and control because you're not limited to working in the SQL Server environment.

Comment: What external application or service would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like a permissions / Access issue on the file location. I would check that the file physically exists and that the Database user (Service Agent) has correct permissions to the file location.